# What is an equivalent method to `GetCustomAttributes` for .NETCore (Windows 8 Framework)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-core

I'm putting together an app that interfaces with Stack API and have been following [this tutorial](http://cgeers.com/2011/10/02/stack-exchange-api/) (although old API version it still works).  My problem is that when using this within the Windows 8 Store App I'm contrained by the .NETCore Framework which doesn't support the `GetCustomAttributes` method found below:

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> ParseJson<T>(string json) where T : class, new()
    {
        var type = typeof (T);
        var attribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (WrapperObjectAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as WrapperObjectAttribute;
        if (attribute == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                String.Format("{0} type must be decorated with a WrapperObjectAttribute.", type.Name));
        }

        var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
        var collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jobject[attribute.WrapperObject].ToString());
        return collection;
    }
```

My question is two-fold.  What exactly does the `GetCustomAttributes` do and is there an equivalent to this method within the constrains of Windows 8 Store App realm?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to use `type.GetTypeInfo()`, which then has various `GetCustomAttribute` methods (via extension methods), or there is `.CustomAttributes` which gives you the raw information (rather than materialized `Attribute` instances).

For example:

```
var attribute = type.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<WrapperObjectAttribute>();
if(attribute == null)
{
    ...
}
...
```

`GetTypeInfo()` is the pain of .NETCore for library authors ;p

If `.GetTypeInfo()` doesn't appear, then add a `using System.Reflection;` directive.

Comment: I spent about two hours trying to find this.  Should have asked sooner :P

Comment: @KronoS heh; I had the pleasure of converting an existing library that made extensive use of reflection... me and .NETCore are now intimately knowledgeable of each-other, and not in a good way. This is just the tip of the iceberg if you do lots of reflection ;p

Comment: One thing to add on .NetCore (with xproj), the TypeInfo extensions are in     "System.Reflection.Extensions" package: "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": { "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
      }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Add the **System.Reflection.TypeExtensions** nugget package to your project; it has GetCustomAttributes extension.

(for VS 2017) something like this.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.6'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions">
        <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```