# .net core equivalent for GetCustomAttribute on assembly?

Tags: reflection, .net-core

I cannot find a .net core equivalent for calling GetCustomAttributes on an assembly object.  I see there is CustomAttributes property, but this doesn't return instances of the custom attributes, but rather metadata about the attributes.  How can I retrieve the actual attribute instance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814723/what-is-an-equivalent-method-to-getcustomattributes-for-netcore-windows-8-fr

Comment: That refers to types, and as as I can see in my code, GetTypeInfo doesn't exist for assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `GetCustomAttributes` extension method. Just add `using System.Reflection`.

Comment: no idea why... I guess tooling still being in preview... but I couldn't get Visual Studio to agree.  Since you stated this as fact, I decided to try again, hard, and so I unloaded/closed/reloaded/put one hand on my head/faced North-east, and suddenly visual studio says the extension method does exist... Thanks!

Comment: @Adam, must be that I don't do this, so I still see the curve lines under GetCustomAttributes?

Comment: The .NET Core version requires a MemberInfo object as the first argument. I'm unsure of what to put in there.