# Hide namespace in 3rd dependent project

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, dependencies, project

I Have 3 projects in same solution, each dependent from the one before (DB <- Provider <- WinUI). In DB I defined a **Behaviour class** that will be used in Providers with a **mapper Behavioud class**, this last used by WinUI project. (WinUI doesn't depend directly from DB).

Is there a way to hide the clases from DB inside WinUI? this project only should use the provider clases.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a small point, you can't really prevent _namespaces_ from being shared, and it shouldn't really matter anyways. The only thing you can restrict is if _types_ are accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, mark the `Behaviour` class in the DB project as `internal`.

Second, add

- for a project that contains an AssemblyInfo.cs file

  ```
  [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Providers")]
  ```
- for .Net 5+, in the csproj file ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501954/how-to-use-a-custom-attribute-on-an-assembly-in-net-core-1-1))

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="Providers" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```

`internal` prevents the class from being visible in other assemblies. The assembly attribute allows sharing internal classes with the assemblies you name.